# Help with Google Bookmarks search skills

Tags: search

Google Bookmarks is a good tools for me，but sometimes i need search tags , the query words should be like this:`label:php`
And i notice the label are case sensitive

if I need to search for more tag，how to input the query words ?

```
label:php and javascript??
```

Comment: Do you want to search using more than one tag at a time?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `label:php AND label:javascript`.